# What is difference between Azure VM & Windows Virtual Desktop?

Tags: azure

What is the significant difference between Azure VM & Windows Virtual Desktop with respect to pricing, features, performance etc

Comment: Windows Virtual Desktop is intended as a hosted (and **licensed and legal**) way for company users to access Microsoft Office and other Windows desktop software over RDP that runs in Microsoft's datacenters (which may or may not be Azure). Azure VMs are IaaS. Azure VMs only come with a license to run their own prepackaged version of Windows, not Office.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dai mentioned, Azure VM is more infrastructure as a service.

However,Windows Virtual Desktop is a modern Microsoft Remote Desktop Azure-based platform service for Virtual desktops that you can use for publishing multi-user Windows 10 desktops, single-user personal virtual desktops

For WVD features you could refer [the article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-desktop/) which might be helpful. Also you could refer [the calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?service=virtual-desktop) for understanding the estimated cost.

So for instance, let us assume that the cost incurred for 500 users :

[image]